# Best Pathfinding solution for 2D action-platformer

Tags: 2d, path-finding, platformer

I'm developing a 2D action RPG with heavy platforming. The combat system and movement take inspiration from Hollow Knight and the Smash Bros saga.

I would like to have some type of enemies with really good tracking of the player, to bring the platforming element to the battles.

I'm trying to find the best way to implement pathfinding for this problem. The enemy has to be able to follow the player between platforms, with (double) jumps, wall jumps, dashes... The most frequent answer that I found researching has been A*, but I'm having trouble implementing it with all these movement capabilities.

Could you help me?

Comment: A* is pretty much THE pathfinding algorithm for single agents. Everything else is just A* with extra optimizations and flourishes. If you've had trouble applying A* to your use case, you should **edit your question** to explain exactly how you've tried implementing it so far, and exactly what trouble you've encountered. We can't help you fix a problem until we know what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, good to know! My question was something more in the realm of "which algorithm would you choose and why". I'm gonna try again with A* and if I still find the same problems, I'm gonna ask for help for the implementation.